# How to update values in json file using read/write mode

Tags: .net, json, .net-4.0, json.net

I have a list of objects serialized in JSON and stored in a file on the disk. I'm using Newtonsoft JSON.net library.

I would like to update some of those stored objects in an efficient way, i.e. instead of overwriting the entire file with new up-to-date list of objects, I would prefer an elegant and performant solution. Something like

- open the file in ReadWrite mode
- seek the correct object, eg. with LINQ to JSON
- modify / replace this object
- flush the changes

I managed to change the data using JsonTextReader, but I don't know how to write the changes back to the open file.

```
public void TestModifyObject(MyClass myClass)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    using (JsonTextReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(jr);
        JToken foundToken = null;
        foreach (JToken jToken in array.Children())
        {
            JToken val = jToken["MyValue"].Value();
            if (val == myClass.MyValue)
            {
                foundToken = jToken;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (foundToken != null)
    {
        JToken myClassToken = JToken.FromObject(myClass);
        foundToken.Replace(myClassToken);

        foreach (JToken jToken in array.Children())
        {
            var newVal = jToken["MyValue"].Value();
            Debug.WriteLine($"value: '{newVal}'"); // prints modified value
        }

        // Now, how do I write the changes back to the file?
    }
}
```

Thanks for any leads ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's a duplicate. Sorry about that, I searched but didn't find that question.